# Drupal 8 - JQuery-ui implementing accordion or tabs in custom module

Tags: jquery-ui, drupal, drupal-8

In Drupal 8 how would an accordion or tab element be implemented in a custom module... for example:

1. A custom module has been set up (including folder structure)... the content function in the module is outputting the following html in the render array (basically pushing the HTML to create the accordion element on to an array which will be appended to the render array, through the use of 'array('#type'=>'markup',"#markup'=>$html)' etc and the code does appear in the HTML page ):

   ```
           array_push($strn,"<div id=".chr(22)."accordion".chr(22).">");
               array_push($strn,"<h3>Section 1</h3>");
                   array_push($strn,"<div>");
                       array_push($strn,"<p>");
                           array_push($strn,"data");
                       array_push($strn,"</p>");
                   array_push($strn,"</div>");
               array_push($strn,"<h3>Section 2</h3>");
                   array_push($strn,"<div>");
                       array_push($strn,"<p>");
                           array_push($strn,"data");
                       array_push($strn,"</p>");
                   array_push($strn,"</div>");
               array_push($strn,"<h3>Section 3</h3>");
                   array_push($strn,"<div>");
                       array_push($strn,"<p>");
                           array_push($strn,"data");
                       array_push($strn,"</p>");
                   array_push($strn,"</div>");
           array_push($strn,"</div>");
   ```
2. The module works itself does work and render HTML
3. Additional javascript file has been loaded via <>.libraries.yml and contains the following code:

   ```
   (function($) {
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#accordion").accordion();
   });})(jQuery);
   ```

... it loads the javascript file as I checked the page's html and the file is there and also added the following line "window.alert("LOADED BESPOKE JS SCRIPT!");" which is successfully executed

3A) For clarities I have added the following code to the <>.libraries.yml file:

```
dataAnalytics.jqui:
  version: VERSION
  header: true
  css:
    theme:
      css/test.css: {}
      css/jquery-ui.css: {}
  js:
    libraries/js/bespokescript1.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.ui.accordion
```

4) Even trying the javascript as the following (Note: The alert command is executed correctly, but the `$("#accordian").accordion();` has no effect although the `alert` command does run):

```
$(function ($) {
//add drupal 7 code
Drupal.behaviors.myfunction = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
    //end drupal calls

    //some jquery goodness here...
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion( {
            header: "li",
            collapsible: true
        } );

        alert("search_results.js properly loaded");
    }
}
});
```

The issue:  The accordion element will not render as an accordion, just as standard HTML text e.g. the JQuery bit is not being executed

Comment: issue resolved...

Comment: issue resolved... part of the issue was with the declaration of header:true in <<modulename>>.libraries.yml file which meant the bespoke file defining the accordion was loading before the Drupal.js file was loading (so received ReferenceError: Drupal error not defined)... the javascript was
(function ($) {
 Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
   $('#accordion').accordion ();
  }
 };
})(jQuery);

Also the line array_push($strn,"<div id=".chr(22)."accordion".chr(22).">"); was changed to drop the chr(22) and replaced with "<div id='accordion'>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes to your code. If you want to use Drupal in your module, put this

```
- core/drupal.ajax
- core/drupal
- core/drupalSettings
```

into your MODULE.libraries.yml under `dependencies`. Or at least `core/drupal`. This says you need drupal for your stuff, so it will load it, before your scripts. This is necessary, because drupal 8 won't load libraries, if none of the modules/themes requires it! Pay attention for this.

Use this, instead of you use in your 4th point:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
    //add drupal 7 code
    Drupal.behaviors.myfunction = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
        //end drupal calls

        //some jquery goodness here...
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion( {
                header: "li",
                collapsible: true
            } );

            alert("search_results.js properly loaded");
        }
    }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

If you don't want to use Drupal, just delete from there. If you use something else too add there. This is some kind of Drupal 8 standard, search this `Drupal.behaviors` under `core` directory and you will find a lot of example.

Comment: @golddrangon007 thanks for taking the time to answer and help with your knowledge, much appreciated